# Wit-ai not abandoning stories

Tags: wit-ai

I have a two stories, one quite basic and the other has some conditional branching.

### Story 1

User says "Menu", bot fires custom action "show_menu".

### Story 2

User says 'Hi'
Fire custom action 'get_activation_state', which sets either schedule_active, or schedule_inactive context attributes.
The story branches.
IF schedule not active then **Bot says** "Blah..You need to activate", **Bot executes** 'show_activation'.  **User says** 'Activate' (This is actually, hopefully, via a postback from messenger).**Bot executes** 'activate_schedule'
IF schedule ACTIVE, **bot says** "How can I help".

All of this works fine if I stick to the script, but if after the activate schedule function fires (which just inserts a button with 'activate') the user chooses to type 'Menu' then Wit (or my use of Wit) needs to be smart enough to abandon its current story line, and start the menu story. Trouble is, its not.

Any help welcomed!

Comment: This shows the conversation (http://recordit.co/DysbI8bO9z).

Comment: what are you trying to acheive exactly? i saw that GIF but still havent understood, btw doing wit.ai for hi bye is not such a great idea, use api.ai for it, its FREE now and its small talk domain is the best for that kinda work